# How to optimize query for "where ... or" SQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

Assuming there's a table users with 2 columns: `first_name`, `last_name`, and it has 1000k records in it.

I want to know, how to optimize this query:

`select * from users where first_name = 'Jim' and last_name = 'Ray'`

I have added index for `first_name` and `last_name` separately, (each index for one row), however it doesn't take effect.

thanks!

Comment: have you tried to create the concatenated index on first_name and last_name ?

Comment: Try adding an index with both first_name and last_name so that SQL can make use of the index.  SQL will not be able to use an index with only one of the columns in it. You can also look at the execution plan to see if the index is being used (look for a seek rather than a scan of the index)

Comment: Questions like this should always include `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output.

Comment: Show us the query plans, otherwise everybody gets stuck in assumptions.

Comment: Your title and your body ask different questions.

Comment: `create index ix1 on users (first_name, last_name)`.